# Infinite refresh loop in React when only one refresh is desired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window

I have a react app with a page with a component on it. What I want to do is to refresh that page only once when you first load it, but all that I have tried, with `window.location.reload()` for example, ends up in a infinite refresh loop.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Post your source code. Is there a particular reason, why you refresh the page on first load?

Comment: After refreshing page all app data also refresh. You need to use SessionStorage for example to bring it to React from out.

Comment: @ArthurKa How can I do that more exactly ? Can you give me a code snippet please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example something like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const reloadCount = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('reloadCount')) || 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    if(reloadCount < 2) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('reloadCount', String(reloadCount + 1));
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      sessionStorage.removeItem('reloadCount');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>{ JSON.stringify({ reloadCount }) }</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: It works but only once, if I go back and forth between pages it doesn't work anymore, can this be modified to work like that ? @ArthurKa

Comment: Here you go. Btw in condinition `reloadCount < n` you can set amount of reloads.

Comment: You're a life saver! One more question, in a class component how should I use this ?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I'm not very familiar with class components.

Comment: An ingenious solution. I was getting an infinite loop :). This worked.